# CakePHP, saving and accessing comma separated MySQL column for "group" identification

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

Say I have a set of pictures, and each picture can belong to one or more groups.

I want to be able to insert into database name, group_ids, and say group ids would be something like '1,2,3'

How can I do this using CakePHP, making sure there aren't duplicate groups (i.e. 1,1,2), and how can I select entries based on one or more groups?

Do I need to do a Model->query, or can this be accomplished with Model->save, and something else for retrieval?

Thanks!

Comment: googling for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MVC applications like this, you shouldn't be doing this. You should be creating a table that acts as in the middle of each other table:

```
TABLE: Pictures

TABLE: Groups
```

Instead of having a column `group_ids` with example value of `1,2,3` you should have a table:

```
TABLE: Grouppictures
COLUMNS: id (per row), PictureID, GroupID
```

...with one row per relationship

In CakePHP for example, you'd create a model called Grouppictures, and you'd set up your model relationships so that you can call all relevant information from the Pictures table **through** the Grouppictures model (which would bring back by a Group ID you pass in for example).

Comment: OK, thanks for explaining.  just jumped in and started doing things, and first time working w/MVC (and pretty much PHP too :D).

Comment: Cool man, it might seem like more work to start with but it actually gives you a much tidier data structure, it's scales easily and it's much easier to find the data you want. Have fun!

Comment: P.S. Cake makes it super easy to do this also

Comment: to me doesn't seem like more work, just that in my mind not the 'efficient' way of doing it (lot more data in MySQL?).  but after your post, I wanted to ask--is  this the 'preferable' way because you can add 'needs' like this w/out changing your entire setup?

Comment: It's a flexible way to do it without a huge amount more data. E.g. if you were extending your table every day adding a new column or ending up with columns of `1,2,3,4` etc, you're creating a nice simple structured data structure that's easy to expand and manipulate. Worth the extra time :)